# SQL Replace into syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, formatting

Im trying to redo a database and everything is in separate replace into statements like so

```
    REPLACE INTO `DB_NAME` VALUES(a,b,c,d);
    REPLACE INTO `DB_NAME` VALUES(a,b,c,d);
    REPLACE INTO `DB_NAME` VALUES(a,b,c,d);
```

I wanted to know if I could reformat that into something like this

```
    REPLACE INTO `DB_NAME`
           (a,b,c,d)
    VALUES (a,b,c,d),
           (a,b,c,d)
```

Im just trying to figure out different ways to write the syntax so its easier to read. The Value fields have about 50 different variables and it gets kind of confusing as to what goes where.

Edit: Using MYSQL btw

Comment: Please specify which database you refer to (MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, Access). Each one maintains their own SQL dialect. Though this sounds like MySQL.

Comment: Add `MySQL` tag to your question then.

Comment: thanks but instead of nitpicking flags can i get some help on the problem at hand?

Comment: It isn't nitpicking. The syntax for statements, and especially for time, date and string handling functions varies greatly between databases. Would it help you if I gave you a solution for SQL Server which didn't work for MySQL?

Comment: Please have a look into this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: No but first, it says in the post that im using mysql after the first person who responded politely asked what db i was using. All Im asking for is help and politeness so when someone comes back and gives neither it doesnt help. Also this is off topic

Comment: And the answer from me is yes, you can use the 2nd syntax and it would be clearer.Here is [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) which describes the syntax.

Comment: @sayani I checked that the problem I had was it didnt give me a real example just plain syntax so it kind of confused me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is generally no problem including additional white-space in MySQL.  So reformatting similar to how you have is fine.

Secondly you can insert (or replace) multiple rows with the syntax you used, however beware that if using a transactional engine such as InnoDB that all row inserts will fail, or succeed.. you won't get a partial completion.   With non-transactional engines such as MyISAM however the changes will occur until the error but any rows after the error will not be processed.  That behavior may be good or bad depending on your situation, you can also look at REPLACE IGNORE which will insert all rows and ignore errors.